# Error undeclared type that I've declared with Bison

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

Bison throws this

> error: $2 of ‘exp’ has no declared type

but I believe I've declared everything.

**FLEX:**

```
[0-9]+ {
yylval.string =yytext; //yes I want ints as strings.
return INT;
}
"*"     {yylval.string=yytext; return MUL;} 
"/"     {yylval.string=yytext; return DIV;} 
"-"     {yylval.string=yytext; return MINUS;} 
"+"     {yylval.string=yytext; return PLUS;} 
"^"     {yylval.string=yytext; return POW;}
```

**BISON:**

```
 %union {
 char * string;
}

%token <string>  INT DEC STRING PLUS MINUS MUL DIV POW
%type <string> OP
.
.
.
 exp: type {foo(x,$1);}
    |exp 
    OP {foo(x,$2);}
    exp; 

OP: PLUS | MINUS| MUL| DIV| POW ;
.
.
.
```

There is a lot more code but this is the part where the error occurs.
When I create a rule for every operator I get no error but I get other problems because of the recursion so I believe I need to do it this way.

Comment: I suspect your actual code is other than what you've posted (you have a simple typo you unconsciously corrected when you summarized it).  Try posting a summary `.y` file that you can actually run through bison and generate the error.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you don't want your flex code to straight up return the value of `yytext`.  It may (well, more than likely will) be overwritten before bison can fully utilize it.  If you want to save the numbers as a string, you'll need to `malloc` and `strdup` them.  For the operators, you probably are best off just setting `yylval.string="+";`, etc, instead of dynamically creating new memory.

Secondly, it seems like something is missing from your bison code.  Before your problem can fully be diagnosed, can you please post the signature of function `foo` as well as the type of `x`?

Thirdly, is this a typo in your bison code?  Should

```
exp: type {foo(x,$1);}
    |exp 
    OP {foo(x,$2);}
    exp;
```

be

```
exp: type {foo(x,$1);}
    |exp OP exp {foo(x,$2);}
    ;
```

?

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Does the last thing you point out matter?

Comment: I hate to say it, but I'm not 100% sure. I just haven't seen bison code written like that before and I would be surprised if it functioned like you want.